# When I run my application use Tomcat, I get java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, tomcat

When I run my application, I get this error information in Server Output:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException

My tomcat config is like this:

[image]

Comment: @224boy, means there is issue in your localhost name, use `$ scutil ––set HostName "localhost"` to set the localhost name in terminal

Comment: @aircraft, thanks, this solved my issue.